# how to import media library in windows store app?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I made a media player windows store app where I used filepicker to pick file from pc to play.
but I want to import the music library and video library and show the content in the homescreen to make it easy selecting files to play. how to do it?
please help..

I'm using c# and xaml for my app.

Comment: Post some code which you have tried? Where are you facing problem?

Comment: i just have no idea about how to import media library, and that's what i wanna learn. till now i'm using filepicker which is working perfectly fine but not the best option for the user in a media player..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what finally worked for me..

```
IReadOnlyList<Windows.Storage.StorageFile> resultsLibrary; 
// to store the library


resultsLibrary = await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName);
// this is the list created.


//and this is what shows the media library in a list in xaml
 length = resultsLibrary.Count;
            list.Items.Clear();


            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
            {
                list.Items.Add(resultsLibrary[j].Name);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you must use the [`KnownFolders`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.knownfolders.aspx) class. You must first add the Music Library and Videos Library capabilities in your app manifest, then you can access them via that class.

Comment: i addded those capabilities but i don't know how to use the knownfolder class. it wud be comfortable for me if you would please help me with it's code.

Comment: There is an example in the link I already posted (to the `KnownFolders` class documentation). You use `KnownFolders.PictureLibrary` (or whichever you're looking for). It returns a `StorageFolder` object. You then treat it like any other `StorageFolder` object. If you still need help after that, then you need to read [How to Read and Write Files in the Windows Store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh758325.aspx)